# ARM NEON use two D registers as a Q register

Tags: c, assembly, arm, inline-assembly, neon

I am trying to load neon register d0 and d1 with data from 2 different arrays and then use it as a 128bit q0 register. According to ARM NEON guide this is possible.

"Neon registers are aliased so that the data in a Q register is the same as that in its two corresponding D registers. For example, q0 is aliased to d0 and d1, and the same data is accessible through either register type."

Tips on what i am doing wrong would be greatly apreciated.

```
 void combine(uint8_t * a, uint8_t * b) { //a = 0-7 b = 8 - 15
  uint8_t *c = malloc(16*sizeof(uint8_t));

  __asm__ (
           "ld1 {v0.8b}, [%1]\n\t"
           "ld1 {v1.8b}, [%2]\n\t"
           "st1 {v0.8h}, [%0]\n\t"
           :
           :"r" (c), "r" (a), "r" (b)
           :
           );
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    printf("%d\t", c[i]); //output 1-7 0 0 0...
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks like AArch64 - as with much of the rest of the ISA, the SIMD register layout there is different from AArch32; significantly, it does away with the overlapping registers thing.

Comment: @Notlikethat Thanks, Is there a similar way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Well, for this _specific_ code, I think it happens that `st1 {v0.8b, v1.8b}, [%0]` would produce the desired final result, due to suitable register choices (n.b. you should be listing v0 and v1 as clobbers). In terms of _actually_ creating a 128 bit vector from two disjoint loads, though, I believe it's simply a case of doing the obvious, i.e. load them, then move the bottom half of v1 into the top half of v0.

Comment: Note that your inline asm isn't safe, because you don't tell the compiler that you're modifying memory.  t doesn't assume that, even though you ask for pointer inputs.  The implied `volatile` (because you have no output operands) doesn't totally guarantee that the optimizer won't assume something you don't want.  You should use intrinsics unless you checked the compiler's asm output and found that you could do a better job than the compiler at tuning for the specific CPU your code will run on.